# UltraComboEditor - Infragistics control

Tags: infragistics

I have an UltraComboEditor (Infragistics control) and the user can input values on it. I used the AutoComplete property to do that.

But now I have a problem. I need to make sure that my user can delete a value that he wrote. I use the function canUndo but it not works.

How can I solve my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to add a ButtonLeft element, perhaps with a red cross image.
Let the user select an item from the combobox and then he/she will press the button element to trigger the action to delete the current selected element.
In the **EditorButtonClick** event you should ask for a confirm, search into your items collection and then remove the one selected.